# Using pgloader to insert array values

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pgloader

So I have a Django DB Model as such:

```
class Film(models.Model):
    title = ArrayField(models.CharField(default='',
        max_length=600), blank=True, null=True)

    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)

    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)

    embed_html = models.CharField(default='',
        max_length=600)

    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)

    tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(default='',
        max_length=600), blank=True, null=True)

    category = ArrayField(models.CharField(default='',
        max_length=600), blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm attempting to use pgload to populate my db with a CSV, yet I run into the error:

*2016-04-24T07:00:53.311000Z ERROR Database error 22P02: malformed array literal: "Random Title Name"
DETAIL: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information*.

Now I understand how to insert array values with raw SQL, I'm just perplexed on how to do so using pgloader. Here's my config aswell.

```
LOAD CSV
    FROM 'first-edit.csv' 
    HAVING FIELDS 
    (
        embed_html, title, tags, category
    )
    INTO postgresql:///tester?test_film
    TARGET COLUMNS
    (
        embed_html, title,tags,category
    )

    WITH fields terminated by ',',
            drop indexes
 ;
```